# Trying to create multiple spark dataframes from each levels of a nested xml file

Tags: python, xml, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

SO I am using databricks community edition to parse an xml file into spark dataframes using pyspark implementation, and want to create multiple dataframes of each level of xml

I have written a block of code where I am reading the xml and flattening the top level nodes to a single dataframe

```
df_xml = spark.read.format('com.databricks.spark.xml').options(rootTag='POSLog',rowTag='Transaction').load(file_location)

from pyspark.sql.functions import *

def flatten_df(nested_df):
    exist = True
    while exist:
        flat_cols = [c[0] for c in nested_df.dtypes if c[1][:6] != 'struct']
        nested_cols = [c[0] for c in nested_df.dtypes if c[1][:6] == 'struct']
        if len(nested_cols) > 0:
          print(nested_cols)
          flat_df = nested_df.select(flat_cols +
                                     [col("`"+nc+'`.`'+c+"`").alias((nc+'_'+c).replace(".","_"))
                                      for nc in nested_cols
                                      for c in nested_df.select("`"+nc+'`.*').columns])
          nested_df=flat_df
          #break
        else:
          exist = False
    return flat_df
df1=flatten_df(df_xml)
display(df1)
```

However, I cannot/don't know how to access the the columns of the dataframe in question so that I can loop through and get the further dataframes.